# Use WP admin AJAX url to hide API key

Tags: ajax, wp-admin, api, curl

Currently I am using `AJAX` to request a simple `JSON` response from an external API. The problem is, that the API key is exposed. I'm aware the best method is to process this through `admin-ajax` and set call the url through PHP. What is the most secure method to do this, and how can this be requested through PHP?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://link.to/api/v2/link?time=day&key=(APIKEYHERE)&response_type=json",
  data: dataString,
  dataType: "json",

  //if received a response from the server
  success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
  }, 
});
```

Comment: to create a AJAX response, you can try this : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would break this problem in to 2 parts.

First, you could sent an Ajax request to your server, sending only the `dataString` variable.

Then, you can use either `cURL` or [`wp_remote_get()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) on the server to access the real API.

This could be the only solution, if you want to avoid playing hide and seek with hashes and writing tons of code just to make it hard for the users to find the API key.

Comment: Thanks Jack! I did indeed end up doing it through AJAX and using cURL to gather the data. Didn't know about `wp_remote_get()`. Are there any benefits to using this over standard cURL?

Comment: You're welcome. Well, it's easier to use though, a more WordPressy way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

**It depends on what the external API offers**, basically **read/write access** to some data.
I think:

- If your website visitor is **allowed** those access/permissions on that data, it is **ok**.
- If your website visitor is **not allowed** those access/permissions on that data, it is **not ok**.

Think of Google and Facebook, they provide **app** and **user** api keys.
That will depends on your use case.
But i can say that **if the external API data access is sensible you should do that on the server and go throw `AJAX` or `REST`**.

Comment: Good points! I was thinking this too. I **do** want the user to be able to filter the `data` parameters of the url so maybe this will be okay. As it's my own external API, I don't want users to use this URL outside the site. Maybe I should look into restricting API requests to the server IP only.

Comment: Look at what other API providers do. They’ll typically limit the number of transactions a key is allowed to perform, and let the user restrict their key to use on a particular domain/server IP.

Comment: Yeah. I ended up just doing it through a proxy by sending the form fields via ajax to a php function and returning results. Not as quick but much more secure :) Thanks!